# Running emacs server via systemd prevents inverse search and nice view

Tags: auctex, emacsclient, emacs24.4, server, system-environment

**Background**: I am using systemd to run my emacs server and my usual workflow always involves invoking emacsclient. Both server and client are on the same computer running Debian Jessie. The method is explained in the following links:

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon#toc8

http://blog.refu.co/?p=1296

https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/3b0qpa/if_you_cant_beat_em_join_em_using_systemd_to/

**Question**: When I work on a Latex document, the view function for AuCTeX used to jump to the pdf document and show a nice redbox; a Ctrl-mouse click successfully performed an inverse search. However, after implementing emacs server as a systemd unit, inverse search does not work any more. In addition, the C-c C-v which is the view function no longer displays the nice red box in the pdf document. How can I fix this problem?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I would like to add that the pdf viewer is evince and the desktop is XFCE 4.10, distributed by Debian.

Comment: Just a guess: maybe those relied on the value of current directory or something like that, which become bogus / unavailable once Emacs is run as a daemon?